# getting error when updating location in background

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, location, android-permissions, foreground-service

I am trying to update the location in the background and foreground so first, I have defined two buttons like update and remove button. so when I click update then it will update the location in the background and remove for removing location listener.

but after some time I want to remove those buttons and when I open that activity then it should update location automatically without button click.

so I decided to remove code from the update button (Start location update) and copy-paste into `oncreate` method. so that it will update whenever activity opened without clicking on the button. now I'm getting null pointer exception pls someone helps me

I am attaching my complete code.

```
 public class UserLocation extends AppCompatActivity implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

DatabaseReference publiclocation;
private static final int MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 7171;
private static final int PLAY_SERVICES_RES_REQUEST = 7172;
private LocationRequest mlocationRequest;
String uid;
SharedPreferences settings;

Button requestLocation, removeLocation;
MyBackgroundService mService = null;
boolean mBound = false;

private final ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder iBinder) {
        MyBackgroundService.LocalBinder binder = (MyBackgroundService.LocalBinder) iBinder;
        mService = binder.getService();
        mBound = true;

    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {

        mService = null;
        mBound = false;
    }
};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_location);

    publiclocation = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Common.PUBLIC_LOCATION);
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    String user_uid = settings.getString("uid", "Null");
    uid = firebaseUser.getUid();



   //Run time permission
    Dexter.withActivity(this)
            .withPermissions(Arrays.asList(
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION

            ))
            .withListener(new MultiplePermissionsListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPermissionsChecked(MultiplePermissionsReport report) {
                    requestLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.request_location_updates_button);
                    removeLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.remove_location_updates_button);

                   //Update location when i click on button
                    requestLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            mService.requestLocationUpdates();
                        }
                    });



                   //Remove location when i click remove button
                    removeLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            mService.removeLocationUpdates();
                        }
                    });



                    setButtonState(Common.requestingLocationUpdates(UserLocation.this));
                    bindService(new Intent(UserLocation.this,
                                    MyBackgroundService.class),
                            mServiceConnection,
                            Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE
                    );
                }

                @Override
                public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(List<PermissionRequest> permissions, PermissionToken token) {

                }


            })
            .check();


}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
            .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {

    if (mBound) {
        unbindService(mServiceConnection);
        mBound = false;
    }
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
            .unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);

    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String s) {


    if (s.equals(Common.KEY_REQUESTING_LOCATION_UPDATES)) {
        setButtonState(sharedPreferences.getBoolean(Common.KEY_REQUESTING_LOCATION_UPDATES, false));
    }


}

private void setButtonState(boolean isRequestEnable) {

    if (isRequestEnable) {
        requestLocation.setEnabled(false);
        removeLocation.setEnabled(true);
    } else {
        requestLocation.setEnabled(true);
        removeLocation.setEnabled(false);
    }
}

@Subscribe(sticky = true, threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onListenLocation(SendLocationToActivity event) {
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    String user_uid = settings.getString("uid", "Null");
    uid = firebaseUser.getUid();
    if (event != null) {
        String data = new StringBuilder()
                .append(event.getLocation().getLatitude())
                .append("/")
                .append(event.getLocation().getLongitude())
                .toString();
        Toast.makeText(mService, data, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //   Location location = event.getLastLocation();

        Locations location = new Locations();
        location.setLat(event.getLocation().getLatitude());
        location.setLon(event.getLocation().getLongitude());


        if (Common.currentUser != null) {
            publiclocation.child(firebaseUser.getUid()).setValue(location);
        } else {
            publiclocation.child(user_uid).setValue(location);

        }


    }
}
```

}

so below is MyLocationService.java

```
   public void requestLocationUpdates() {

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Came",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Common.setRequestingLocationUpdates(this, true);
    startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyBackgroundService.class));
    try {
        fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        Log.e("FunDrive", "Lost location permissions.could not request it" + e);

    }
}
```

Common java

```
  public static final String KEY_REQUESTING_LOCATION_UPDATES = "LocationUpdatedEnable";
SharedPreferences settings;

public static final int TIME_DISPLAY_SLOT_TOTAL = 20;
//Current User
public static User currentUser;


public static String PUBLIC_LOCATION="PublicLocation";
public static boolean isTimeSelected = false;

  public static void setRequestingLocationUpdates(Context context,boolean value) {

    PreferenceManager.
            getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
            .edit()
            .putBoolean(KEY_REQUESTING_LOCATION_UPDATES,value)
            .apply();

}

public static boolean requestingLocationUpdates(Context context) {
    return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
            .getBoolean(KEY_REQUESTING_LOCATION_UPDATES,false);
}

public static CharSequence getLocationTitle(com.example.fundrive.MyBackgroundService myBackgroundService) {
    return String.format("Location Updated :%1$s", DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date()));
}
```

below is what I tried in `oncreate` method

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mService.requestLocationUpdates();
    }
```